# java.lang.NullPointerException error. How to initialize class?

Tags: java

I am pretty new to java and I am trying to write a simple game but I am getting this error in my program "java.lang.NullPointerException" couldn't figured out why I am getting this so I am posting my code here.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("How many players?:");
       int t = console.nextInt();
       Player p[] = new Player[t];
       for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
           System.out.println("Player " + i+1 + " enter your name:");
           p[i].player_name = console.nextLine();
           System.out.println(p[i].player_name + " Easy(1), Medium(2), Hard(3), enter one integer");
           p[i].number = console.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Player " + i+1 + "name: " + p[i].player_name + "your integer is " + p[i].number);
      }
   }
```

And this is my Player class

```
public class Player {
   public String player_name;
   public int number;

   public Player() {
       this.player_name = " ";
       this.number = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: at the beginning of your loop you need to add `p[i] = new Player();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array elements of `Object` types are `null` by default. Create an instance of `Player` before attempting to assign its fields

```
for (int i=0; i<t; i++) {
   p[i] = new Player();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your `p[i]` first. You can put this at the start of the for-loop inside the loop:

```
p[i] = new Player();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you make an array of players but you dont fill it with a player

```
Player p[] = new Player[t];
```

do this in you loop first

```
p[i] = new Player();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that this statement does

```
Player p[] = new Player[t];
```

is just allocating memory for t references to the Player objects. It does not initialize any Player object, so these references referes to null objects, therefore when you invoke

```
p[i].player_name
```

you get the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the instantiation of the new player objects inside the for loop.
When you declare the array with: `Player p[] = new Player[t];`, you are just creating the array of type Player. Before assigning values inside the loop, instantiate an object in the proper position of the array. i.e:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
   p[i] = new Player();
}
```